# Shell jq is adding header to every other line in csv output, not just once at the top

Tags: json, shell, csv, header, jq

I am extracting keys from a `json` with this format:

```json
[
 {
   "k1":{"k2":4},
   "k3":{"k2":6}
 }
]
[
 {
   "k1":{"k2":4},
   "k3":{"k2":6}
 }
]
```

I am using this command `["a","b"], (.[] | [.k1.k2,.k3.k2]) | @csv` to extract two keys and adding two headers (`a`, `b`) to the csv. But The output to this is a header in every other line:

```
"\"a\",\"b\""
"4,6"
"\"a\",\"b\""
"4,6"
```

You can see this in this [jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/VWOZCeaKLZ). How can I change to filter to just put header on the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have stream in your json, you need `inputs` instead of `.[]`

```
jq -nr '(["a","b"], (inputs | map(.k1.k2,.k3.k2))) | @csv' input-json
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input is a stream of JSON documents. Thus, your filter gets executed once for each document, including constructing the headers.

One solution would be to use the `--slurp` or `-s` option to read in the stream as an array. This, however, would necessitate to go one level deeper in your iteration (`.[][]` instead of just `.[]`):

```
jq -s '["a","b"], (.[][] | [.k1.k2,.k3.k2]) | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mLmpcEogcH)

Another way would be to use `inputs` which gives you all input documents at once. This, however, would necessitate to iterate over that (`input[]` instead of `.[]`) and use the `--null-input` or `-n` flag to avoid swallowing up the first elemment:

```
jq -n '["a","b"], (inputs[] | [.k1.k2,.k3.k2]) | @csv'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WewrznwJlu)

Note: You also may want to use the `--raw-output` or `-r` flag to produce raw text instead of JSON when generating the output with `@csv` (as I already did in the demos).